# Angular momentum and rotation group representations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

In Sakurai's book it's written that the operator $D_{m',m}^{(j)}=\left\langle{j,m'}\Big|\exp{\frac{-i \mathbf{ J\cdot \hat{n} } \phi}{\hbar}}\Big|{j,m}\right\rangle$ is the "$2j+1$-dimensional irreducible representation of the rotation operator". I was wondering whether there is a simple way to prove that it is irreducible (if it's not obvious for some reasons I'm missing).

For example, considering $j=1$ and the vector space generated by the eigenkets of $J^2$ and $J_z$, how can I show that the components of the angular momentum generate an irreducible representation?

My idea would be to use the fact that any other operator that commutes with $J_x$, $J_y$ and $J_z$ is a multiple of the identity (which is proved easily) and then use some sort of converse of Schur's lemma, if it even exists.

I'm not even sure this is the best way to tackle the problem, as I only know the most basic things about group theory.

Comment: Actually the solution to this is via the ladder operators $\hat L_\pm$.  Acting on the top state $\vert j,j\rangle$, laddering down will generate a finite dimensional space that is by definition irreducible.

Comment: To vulgarize the above comment of @ZeroTheHero even more, for your j=1 triplet posited, if it were reducible, it would contain a singlet, so an eigenvector of all $J_z,J_+,J_-$, which you can *see* is not achievable.

Comment: Neither of the comments are fully rigorous. A finite-dimensional representation is not necessarily irreducible, nor is any representation not containing a singlet necessarily irreducible. An example contradicting both claims is the representation formed from the direct product of a $j=1/2$ rep with a $j = 1$ rep.

Comment: I don't understand why the fact that ladder operators generate a finite dimensional space implies that the representation is irreducible. Shouldn't I prove that there aren't any non-trivial subrepresentations? Intuitively, I see that if I only took two eigenstates (for example with $m=1$ and $m=0$), I could obtain, through a certain rotation, a vector that  has a $m=-1$ component and that therefore doesn't belong to the space generated by the other two. Is this what you meant or is it something even more trivial?

Comment: @LukePritchett. My comment focusses narrowly on the restricted j=1 choice of the OP, where the triplet *must* contain a singlet to be reducible, *right* ?  Further, your direct product example is  manifestly Clebsch-reducible, ie, it lacks a *single quadratic casimir eigenvalue j(j+1)* as posited!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Consider the direct sum (not direct product) of two $j=1$ representations. It has a single quadratic Casimir eigenvalue but is reducible.

Comment: I just realized ZeroTheHero's comment was probably not claiming that finite-dimensional representations are irreducible, but that a representation generated by acting with all the ladder operators starting from a single state is irreducible. That is pretty much how the proof goes.

Comment: Is the question you are asking how to prove that the specific expression you copied is irreducible, or is it how to prove that the irreducible representations of $SU(2)$ come in $2j+1$ dimensional spaces labelled by the number $j$? The first question is kind of trivial; Sakurai is just defining the notation for matrix elements of the matrices in the $2j+1$ matrices. The second question is non-trivial but I'm sure has been answered on this site.

Comment: @LukePritchett Indeed, 34 j=1 triplets are reduced; but just one isn’t.

Comment: @LukePritchett I understand how ladder operators work and how they give, in the case of angular momentum, $2j+1$ eigenvectors of $J^2$ (and of $J_z$). I really don't see how this implies that there aren't any non-trivial rotation-invariant subspaces (subspaces of the space generated by the $2j+1$ eigenvectors). I think this corresponds to the second question in your second comment. I couldn't find an answer, probably it's because my knowledge of group theory is very limited.

Comment: @Gnegne But you got *all* these 2j+1 states by laddering with the $J_\pm$ operators, so they *are* all connected by them. How could they now be found to be disconnected? The j=1 case should be self-evident. It is easy to find an eigenvector of $J_z, J_+$, a null vector of the latter, but it is impossible to *also*   have it be an eigenvector of $J_-$ as well. Behold the 3x3 operators! Sakurai constructs these multiplets recursively, in finding the irreps.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Reading Sakurai's construction, I only see how to obtain the $2j+1$ simultaneous eigenstates of $J^2$ and $J_z$. How is this connected to irreducible representations? How can you be sure that, for $j=2$, in the space $V=span(\lvert -2 \rangle+\lvert -1 \rangle+\lvert 0 \rangle+\lvert 1 \rangle+\lvert 2 \rangle, \lvert -2 \rangle+\lvert -1 \rangle, \lvert 0 \rangle + \lvert 1 \rangle, \lvert -2 \rangle+\lvert 2 \rangle)$
is not rotation invariant? In my head, the absence of such invariant subspaces is what you need to prove for irreducibility

Comment: They are not invariant by construction. Linearly algebraicaly, one was laddered from the other: do the explicit exercise!

Comment: @CosmasZachos So you are saying that the only invariant subspace is, roughly speaking, the one generated by all the states obtained with ladder operators, right? But why is it the only one? What does it mean if another set is obtained from this using ladder operators? I think that the meaning of ladder operators from a rotations group point of view isn't clear at all to me, what do they represent?

Comment: They are in the Lie algebra. Think of them as infinitesimal complex rotations.

Comment: What does a rotation of a complex angle mean?

Comment: @LukePritchett no I was not claiming this as you realized after; just that a highest weight is a cyclic vector for this type of algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a sketch of proof.

Any transformation can be factored in a sequence of upper triangular matrix (UT), a diagonal matrix (D) and a lower triangular (LT).  Thus an arbitrary element $R\in SU(2)$ will have the form
\begin{align}
R(\boldsymbol{\phi})e^{-i \vec \phi\cdot \vec L}= UT(\phi)\cdot D(\phi)\cdot LT(\phi)\, .
\end{align}
This decomposition is basically the same as writing the transformation as
\begin{align}
R(\boldsymbol{\phi})=e^{-i\vec\phi\cdot\vec L}=e^{\zeta(\phi)L_-}
\cdot e^{-i\beta(\phi) L_z}\cdot e^{\xi(\phi)L_+} \tag{1}
\end{align}
i.e. in antinormal-ordered form, where $\zeta,\xi $ and $\beta$ are functions of the original parameters $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ of the transformation.  If one uses the Euler parametrization of elements in $SU(2)$ then you can find these $\zeta$ etc in multiple sources (v.g. Perelomov’s book on coherent states)

It is then clear that, acting on the highest weight states, (1) amounts to repeatedly acting on this state by the lowering operator $L_-$.  By construction, if $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ is a generic element then there cannot be any invariant subspace.

Note that this relies on the action of (1) on the *unique* highest weight state in your space.  For instance, if you consider the Hilbert space for two spin-1/2 systems, then each of the irreducible subpieces $S=0$ and $S=1$ has a highest weight so acting on the $\vert{+}\rangle\vert{+}\rangle$ (the highest weight of the $S=1$ subspace, generates a $3$-dimensional irreducible subspaces which does not “access” the $S=0$ subspace, and a rotation of the uncoupled $\vert{+}\rangle \vert -\rangle$ does not generate an irreducible subspace as this state is not a highest weight.